# Библиотека для чтения shapefile shp shx. C#

Tags: c#, поиск-библиотек, shape

Всем доброго времени суток!

Сейчас делаю маленький проект, в котором нужна интерактивная политическая карта мира, позволяющая пользователю с помощью мышки выбрать страну.

Поискав в гугле, нашёл [вот этот сайт](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php), с которого можно скачать карту в форматах shp и shx.

Собственно, подскажите пожалуйста хорошую библиотеку для чтения файлов этих форматов. (По аналогии с [вот этой библиотекой](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=netdxf) для чтения dxf)

Заранее благодарю

Comment: Здесь [искать](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=Esri+Shapefile&type=Repositories) пробовали?

Comment: Изучил вашу ссылку. Там нет библиотек - есть программы-ридеры. Есть программа для конвертирования в GeoJson, но это не то, что мне нужно.

Но всё равно спасибо